# How can I access the nodes by Id in cytoscape.js?

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js

```
cy.add([
        {group: "nodes", data: {id: "default"}, renderedPosition: pos},
        ]);
```

I want to access this node by id. and then change it's Id to something else. I tried accessing the node by 
    `$("#default").attr("id", nodeId );// where nodeId is a varaible.`

It doesn't works as it is not an attribute of the node. How can I access this node?

Answer (score 1):

ID is immutable in graphs.  Consider edges are defined by their connecting nodes, and also consider compound nodes.

`.attr()` is not a function.  And it looks like you're using jQuery rather than cy.js for searching.  Please refer to [the docs](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/graph-manipulation/cy.%24)